# Ruby analog of Java ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Does Ruby have analog of Java ScheduledExecutorService?

Instead this:

```rb
Thread.new do
  while true 
    puts "Do something..."
    sleep 1
  end
end
```

Use something like this:

```rb
ScheduledExecutorService.new(timeout) do
  puts "Do something..."
end
```

It's not so critical but more compact and clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a standard solution, but you can use [`Thread`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fiber.html)s in order to implement it:

```
class ScheduledExecutor
  def threads
    @threads ||= []
  end

  def initialize(options = {}, &block)
    schedule options, &block unless block.nil?
  end

  def schedule(options = {}, &block)
    period = options.fetch :period, nil
    delay = options.fetch :delay, 0
    threads << Thread.new do
      sleep delay
      begin
        block.call
      end while period and sleep period
    end
  end
end

# Will it work?
puts Time.now; ScheduledExecutor.new(delay: 1, period: 2) { puts Time.now }
2012-04-09 14:46:57 -0300
2012-04-09 14:46:58 -0300
2012-04-09 14:47:00 -0300
2012-04-09 14:47:02 -0300
2012-04-09 14:47:04 -0300
2012-04-09 14:47:06 -0300
2012-04-09 14:47:08 -0300
2012-04-09 14:47:10 -0300
```